# Is this a good way of using inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Is this a good way of using inheritance?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Test::A {
    class A {
        char const * const this_message;

    public:
        constexpr A(char const * const message) noexcept
            : this_message(message) {
        }

        constexpr char const * message() const noexcept {
            return this_message;
        }
    };

    struct B : public A {
        constexpr B(char const * const message) noexcept
            : A(message) {
        }
    };
}

int main() {

    std::cout << sizeof(Test::A::A) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(Test::A::B) << '\n';

    std::cout << Test::A::B("Test 1").message() << '\n';

    try {

        char const * const Test4 = "Test 4";

        // Uncomment / comment to toggle between
        //throw Test::A::B("Test 1");
        throw Test::A::B(Test4);

    } catch (Test::A::A const a) {
        // I'm passing 'a' by copy because the size of 'a'
        // will always be either 4 or 8 bytes / it's faster this way.
        constexpr auto message = Test::A::B("Test 3").message();

        std::cout << a.message() << " " << message << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've got 2 questions:

A) Is this a good way of using inheritance and...

B) Is this program correct, well formed and without undefined behaviour?

I want to create my own simple two level exception hierarchy (only one base class and some derived classes) and I'm trying to find an way of doing it without any virtual methods.

The following code does work and it seems to call the destructors in the correct order, even though there's nothing to destruct on the derived class. I am however a bit puzzled by how the internals of this work.

I know that I need a virtual destructor if I wish to delete a derived class through its base pointer, but I'm not thinking about supporting that sort of polymorphism.

I know that by calling the `message` method from `B`, I'm just calling the method from `A`, which in turn just returns the member variable `this_message`, which can be either initialized in `A` or `B`.

When passing the object to the catch call, is the `B` object turned into an `A` by the process of slicing? But because B just initializes a member of `A` / have the same state as `A`, it all works out in the end.

The idea is for the `A` class and its derived classes to be initialized in a macro by passing a static char array containing line number, file location, etc.

Comment: It's just an habit that I like to maintain, I'll `const` everything that I can. Still, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It's not clear why `B` needs to exist at all. Also, I'm not certain the rule of thumb that says passing a small and trivially copyable type by value in a function parameter is a bit faster than passing by reference is also true of exception handler parameters.

Comment: With such a trivial example there's not much that can be said with regards to whether it's a "good" example of inheritance or not. Aside from that, throw exceptions that ultimately derive from `std::exception`, and always catch them by reference otherwise you might end up slicing your exceptions and throwing away information.

Comment: `B` needs to exist because it will represent a completely new type of exception with a completely different contextual meaning.

Comment: Using macros in C++ is (which you say in the last sentence is where you are going with this) is, more often than not, very bad technique in C++.

Comment: How can you use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` elegantly without wrapping the exception in a macro like `THROW_EXCEPTION(Ex) throw Ex("Excepion thrown from " __FILE__)`. I know how to use and tame my own macros, I just want to know if the code that I gave is well defined in C++.

Comment: "a completely new type of exception with a completely different contextual meaning" In this case can you still say that `B` is-a `A`? If not, then probably not a good case for inheritance.

Comment: I want to be able to catch on both `B` and `A`, being that `A` must catch himself and all it's derived classes. My code works and the correct message is always shown. And it works without virtual methods. It may be a hack, but it seems to me to be a well defined one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I need a virtual destructor if I wish to delete a derived class through its base pointer, but I'm not thinking about supporting that sort of polymorphism.

Those kind of compromises can be practical if you're the only programmer working on a project, but are something you'd need to communicate to and enforce with every person joining the project, so you're making it hard to scale or reuse the code you write.

> When passing the object to the catch call, is the B object turned into an A by the process of slicing? But because B just initializes a member of A / have the same state as A, it all works out in the end.

Yes, by slicing.  Yes, it hangs together.

> The idea is for the A class and its derived classes to be initialized in a macro by passing a static char array containing line number, file location, etc.

And that's another issue / gotcha: people are used to `std::exception` capturing the text in an internal `std::string`, so other programmers would have to be warned away from doing things like `Test::A::B(my_message_in_a_string.c_str());` and `Test::A::B(my_ostringstream.str())`, making it significantly harder to put a useful message into your exception classes.

> A) Is this a good way of using inheritance and...

It grants you the option of catching by base (whether by reference or slicing) or derived type, so inheritance adds useful functionality.

> B) Is this program correct, well formed and without undefined behaviour?

It is, but it's fragile in the face of maintenance and hard to extend given the lack of virtual functions and use of slicing.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful and well constructed answer. :) This is for a strictly personal project of mine where I get to dictate my own rules and conventions. And all I want is a simple and lightweight exception class that doesn't depend on external libraries. And this probably not very used strategy works really well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the standard library std::cout so definitely you should derive your Exceptions from std::exception.

The name of your class should be named appropriately, like SomethingException.

Initialising your class with a pointer seems wrong even if it is to something in .const section. You have initialised the pointer in the stack that is going to unwind. That pointer, will die before the copy in your class instance does because it is thrown. It will work because the address is .const but it smells and will cause future maintainers to scratch their head.

So: 
A - not a good form of inheritance.
B - The behaviour is defined albeit smelly ;-)

Comment: About the names, those were just placeholders, and the `std::cout` was just to see the results on screen. Like I said in previous comments, all exceptions will be initialized and thrown through a macro that will construct a static compile time char array, thus reducing to zero the pointer and unwiding problems. Thanks for the answer :)